# SensorEventListener question for Android Things

Tags: android-sensors, android-things

i am creating an driver for HTS221 Sensor on Sensehat for Raspberry Pie on Android Things. It works fine but now i am trying to create a Android Sensor out of it.

I am using bmx280driver as a reference, couse i am a newbie coder.

I dont understand the SensorEventListener.

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
SensorEventListener mListener = ...;
Bmx280SensorDriver mSensorDriver;
```

Here is a snippet of how the bmx280 Sensor should be initiialized.

My problem is here:

```
SensorEventListener mListener = ...;
```

...; should be something but i dont know what.

I just have

```
SensorEventListener mListener;
```

and it makes mListener = null

Please help

Kind Regards Daniel

Answer (score 0):

[`SensorEventListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener) is a class that receives callbacks from the SensorManager when there is new data from a sensor.

You should initialize the object and implement the abstract methods.

```
SensorEventListener mListener = new SensorEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // Handle new data
  }
}
```

You can check out [sample implementations](https://github.com/androidthings/weatherstation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/weatherstation/WeatherStationActivity.java#L138) like the [weatherstation](https://github.com/androidthings/weatherstation) sample.